# HTC One M8 Not Recognized When Plugged In On Mac or PC

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Forgive me if I'm not technical enough here - I'm new, and not terribly comfortable with speaking about coding, given that I'm in QA.

I'm running into a problem when I try to connect my HTC One M8 to my Mac or PC. I've got it running in Debugging mode without problem, but when I connect it to either system, it's not recognized by either Android Studio or the HTC Sync Manager. When it's plugged in, I don't get the shade to appear letting me know it's plugged in as an MTP device - it defaults automatically to just charging. Anything anyone can tell me to fix this error so I can attach crash logs to my bugs to make my developers lives a little easier?

Comment: Simple question, but you've gone in and tapped 'about phone' to unlock developer tools, and turned on USB debugging? Just making sure it's not something too simple.

Comment: Agreed. While on Windows you have to fuss with manufacturer-specific device drivers, on OS X and Linux, often times it "just works" if USB debugging is enabled. Note, though, that the recipe to enable the Developer Tools portion of Settings is to go into Settings > About, find the row for the "build number", and tap that seven times. You should get a `Toast` (a popup bubble) telling you that you are now a developer, and a "Developer Tools" section should now appear back in the main Settings screen.

Comment: Yup, I'm already in Developer mode and have the Developer Tools section in my Settings, with 'Enable USB Debugging' checked.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consult the official Developers guide regarding connecting a phone to Android Studio [Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

In case it doesn't solve your problems, you may want to check that your USB port is currently accepting your device: in my computer, if I connect my phone to the USB 3.0 port I can use Android Studio but not Fastboot, while connecting to a USB 2.0 port does exactly the opposite.

Finally, you may want to check that the phone drivers are correctly installed: I don't own a HTC phone, but it may require a special procedure to install its own drivers.